# Find probability of getting 1 and 0 (separately) in boolean expression (((x&x)^x)|x).

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, boolean-algebra

In this problem, I have to find probability of getting 1 and 0 in the boolean expression whose format has been shown above.

I have done this for two-variable like (x&x).
In this, we will have a total of 4 choices. They are (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1).
From which we get P(1)=1/4 and P(0)=1/4.

But I am struggling at how can I generalize this for n terms like (((x&x)^x)&...|(x^x))
I have to represent the probability in P/Q format where gcd(P, Q)=1

Looking forward to your help.
Thank You

Comment: What are the definitions of the $|$ and $\text{^}$ symbols? Without knowing this we can't answer your question.

Comment: | - (bitwise or) and ^ - ( bitwise xor )